# How to get this dcast'able long table in R?

Tags: r, data-structures

I am trying to apply `dcast` on long table, continua from the thread answer [How to get this data structure in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128640/54964) 
Code

```
dat.m <- structure(c(150L, 60L, 41L, 61L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("ave_max", "ave", "lepo"), NULL))
library("ggplot2")
library("data.table")
dat.m <- melt(as.data.table(dat.m, keep.rownames = "Vars"), id.vars = "Vars") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128640/54964
dat.m

print("New step")
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/44090815/54964
minmax <- dat.m[dat.m$Vars %in% c("ave_max","lepo"), ]
absol  <- dat.m[dat.m$Vars %in% c("ave"), ]
#minm   <- dcast(minmax, Vars ~ variable)
minm   <- dcast(minmax, Vars ~ ...)
absol <- merge(absol, minm, by = "Vars", all.x = T)

absol

#Test function    
ggplot(absol, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill = variable)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lepo, ymax = ave_max), width = .25)
```

Output

```
dcast, melt

      Vars variable value
1: ave_max       V1   150
2:     ave       V1    60
3:    lepo       V1    41
4: ave_max       V2    61
5:     ave       V2     0
6:    lepo       V2     0
[1] "New step"
   Vars variable value V1 V2
1:  ave       V1    60 NA NA
2:  ave       V2     0 NA NA
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lepo' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... by_layer -> f -> <Anonymous> -> f -> lapply -> FUN -> FUN
Execution halted
```

Expected output: to pass the test function `ggplot`

### Testing Uwe's proposal

Aim is to get to this data structure

```
dat.m <- structure(c(150L, 60L, 41L, 61L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("ave_max", "ave", "lepo"), NULL))
```

from this data structure

```
dat.m <- structure(list(ave_max = c(15L, 6L), ave = c(6L, NA), lepo = c(4L, NA)), .Names = c("ave_max", "ave", "lepo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Attempts

```
dat.m <- structure(list(ave_max = c(15L, 6L), ave = c(6L, NA), lepo = c(4L, NA)), .Names = c("ave_max", "ave", "lepo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

# ...
```

1. Code and output

   ```
   dat.m <- setDT(dat.m)
   ```

   Output wrong

   ```
           ave_max      ave      lepo
   1:           15        6         4
   2:            6       NA        NA
   Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
     $ ave_max: int  15 6
     $ ave    : int  6 NA
     $ lepo   : int  4 NA
     - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
   ```
2. Code and output

   ```
   dat.m <- as.matrix(dcast(melt(setDT(dat.m), measure.vars = names(dat.m)), variable ~ rowid(variable))[, variable := NULL]); 
   dimnames(dat.m) <- list(names(dat.m), NULL);
   ```

   Output wrong

   ```
    Error in `:=`(variable, NULL) : 
   Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. 
    See help(":=").
   ```

R: 3.4.0 (backports)
OS: Debian 8.7.

Comment: Please, remove the call to  `library("reshape2")` as `data.table` has it's own fast implementations of `melt()` and `dcast()`.

Comment: And also see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131736/3817004) to your question [How to do histograms of this row-column table in R ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44030346/3817004).

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your questions if you (1) edit essential parts of your Q, (2) use the same variable name `dat.m` for different objects. Better to stay with `dat.m` for a matrix object and `dat.df` for a data.frame object. My answer below has been tested to produce the result as shown from the given data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has edited his question and is supplying the data as a data.frame:

```
dat.df <- structure(list(ave_max = c(15L, 6L), ave = c(6L, NA), lepo = c(4L, NA)), 
                    .Names = c("ave_max", "ave", "lepo"), class = "data.frame", 
                    row.names = c(NA, -2L))

dat.df
#  ave_max ave lepo
#1      15   6    4
#2       6  NA   NA
class(dat.df)
#[1] "data.frame"
```

He is now asking to transform this data.frame into a matrix which is similar to the one used as input data in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132425/3817004).

This can be achieved by using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# transpose the input data frame, use rowid() to create columns,
# remove a character column to ensure matrix will be of type integer,
# finally, coerce to matrix
dat.m2 <- as.matrix(
  data.table::dcast(
    data.table::melt(setDT(dat.df), measure.vars = names(dat.df)), 
    variable ~ rowid(variable)
  )[, variable := NULL]
)
# add row names, remove column names
dimnames(dat.m2) <- list(names(dat.df), NULL)

dat.m2
#        [,1] [,2]
#ave_max   15    6
#ave        6   NA
#lepo       4   NA

str(dat.m2)
# int [1:3, 1:2] 15 6 4 6 NA NA
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "ave_max" "ave" "lepo"
#  ..$ : NULL

class(dat.m2)
#[1] "matrix"
```

**Edit**: I've amended above code to use the double colon operator to explicitely state the namespace from which `melt()` and `dcast()` should be taken. Normally, this wouldn't be necessary as `data.table` is already loaded. However, the OP is reporting issues which might be caused by package `reshape2` being loaded after `data.table`. The `data.table` package has it's own faster implementations of `reshape2::dcast()` and `reshape2::melt()`. When both packages have been loaded for some reason name clashes might occur.

Comment: Make sure that the input data set is a data.table or a data.frame which is coerced by using `setDT()`. In addition, I respectfully suggest to disclose the full context of your various questions. For instance, the link you cited is  not about using `data.table` within a function but within a function which is part of a package.

Comment: Found my mistake: `library(reshape2)` in another function, complicating the case. Maybe, I should start using some API to limit such events in the future; etc to say which packages are acceptable in functions. Is that possible?

Comment: Where possible, I prefer to use the double colon operator, e.g., `stringr::str_replace()` rather than loading the whole package, e.g., `library(stringr)` and somewhere else in the code `str_replace()`. So, it might help to write `data.table::melt()`or `data.table::dcast()` just in case `library(reshape2)` has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has supplied data as a matrix:

```
dat.m <- structure(c(150L, 60L, 41L, 61L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
  c("ave_max", "ave", "lepo"), NULL))

#    dat.m
#        [,1] [,2]
#ave_max  150   61
#ave       60    0
#lepo      41    0
class(dat.m)
#[1] "matrix"
```

For this data set, the OP wants to use `ggplot2` to create a bar chart with error bars where the height of the bars is given by the values of `ave` and the lower and upper limits of the error bars by `lepo` and `ave_max`, resp., in each column.

As `ggplot2` expects data to be supplied as data.frame the data needs to be transformed. For this, `data.table` is used:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used

# convert to data.table & transpose
transposed <- dcast(melt(as.data.table(dat.m, keep.rownames = "Vars"), 
                         id.vars = "Vars"), variable ~ ...)
setnames(transposed, "variable", "Vars")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(transposed, aes(x = Vars, y = ave, ymin = lepo, ymax = ave_max)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(width = .25)
```

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Try `dat.m2 <- as.matrix(dcast(melt(setDT(dat.df), measure.vars = names(dat.df)), variable ~ rowid(variable))[, variable := NULL]); dimnames(dat.m2) <- list(names(dat.df), NULL); dat.m2`

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 How is `DT` created? What returns `str(DT)`?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 You need to coerce the data.frame to data.table using `setDT(dat.m)`.